# checkbox click shows me undefined when setting state

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I added a checkbox to my rendered HTML of my react.

When checked, I want it to fire a function called `handleChange`.

That `handleChange` function will take the value of the `checkbox` and then use that value to filter an array called `bookshelfsArray`.

But when I click the checkbox, I see an error in the console:

`filterStore is undefined`

But I set the value of `filterStore` to "360" when I'm testing, so it should be fine.

Is there anything else I need to set for this to work?

Thanks!

Here is my full code file I am testing:

```
import React from 'react';
import { theLibraryData } from 'data';

function bookshelfRow(props) {
return (
        <div>
            <div>{title}</div>
        </div>
        )

}

export default class bookshelfDemo extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            bookshelfs: theLibraryData,
            filterStore: 0
        };
    }

    handleChange = e => {
        const { value } = e.target;
        console.log("You checked the checkbox!");
        this.setState({filterStore:value})
    }

    render() {

        let bookshelfsArray = this.state.bookshelfs;

        bookshelfsArray = bookshelfsArray.filter(x => x.storeId === filterStore);

        return (
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" name="test" onChange={this.handleChange} value="360" />
                {bookshelfsArray.map((bookshelf) => <bookshelfRow key={bookshelf.id} bookshelf={bookshelf} />)}
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're issue has to do with the fact that you are referencing `filterStore` versus what I think you want to reference `this.state.filterStore`, located on this line:

```
bookshelfsArray = bookshelfsArray.filter(x => x.storeId === filterStore);
```

Since the variable `filterStore` has never been assigned, it is undefined. Fix it like this:

```
bookshelfsArray = bookshelfsArray.filter(x => x.storeId === this.state.filterStore);
```

Additionally, you should know that they way you are using `setState` in the line below:

```
this.setState({ filterStore: value })
```

Actually sets your library data to undefined, since when you update the state object, this field is cleared. You can fix this with the following:

```
this.setState({ filterStore: value, ...this.state })
```

Comment: Hi!  I am not sure this is working because when I click the checkbox nothing happens.  I put a `console.log` in the `handleChange` and I do see that getting fired.  But the page is never refreshed after the checkbox click

Comment: thank you, I did added the `...this.state` line and changed it to `x.storeId === this.state.filterStore` but nothing happens except the console.log in `handleChange`

Comment: `this.setState({ filterStore: value })` doesn't set library to `undefined`, it will update only `filterStore`. And `this.setState({ filterStore: value, ...this.state })` is incorrect, this way `this.state` will overwrite `filterStore: value` with its `filterStore` property value. the correct way to create a new object with new values is spreading the old object first.

Comment: @buzatto Thanks! So I do this? `this.setState({ ...this.state, filterStore: value  })`

Comment: your original is correct actually, `SetState` doesn't need to return the whole state object. But if it needed that would be the correct way. you can do  `this.setState({ ...this.state, filterStore: value  })` or `this.setState({ filterStore: value })`, the outcome will be the same

Comment: @buzatto thanks, I tried both `this.setState({ ...this.state, filterStore: value });` and `this.setState({ filterStore: value });` inside my `handleChange` function but both return an empty array.  I verified that I am using the correct `filterStore` number.  I also verified that the `handleChange` function is getting the value of 360 by adding console.logs

Comment: @buzatto I wonder if it's because in the checkbox, `value="360"` is a string?

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell is `x.storeId` correct, or should it be `x.id`? it could be that you are comparing string with number as you say...

Comment: @buzatto Yep, it was a type issue...this fixed it! `x.storeId === parseInt(this.state.filterStore)`

Comment: Thank you @buzatto, I did not know that both of those `setState()` lines did the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

you should use :

```
bookshelfsArray = bookshelfsArray.filter(x => x.storeId === this.state.filterStore);
```

Comment: Please explain why this might resolve the OP's problem.